# .ssh folder permitted to 777

Tags: 16.04, ssh

I am using Ubuntu in AWS. By mistake, I was given the permission 777 to all subfolders of the main root directory. Changes also applied to the .ssh folder. Now I am unable to login AWS Instance by using SSH method. How can I change the permission of .ssh folder? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what access do you currently have to the server? It sounds like you are unable to SSH, do you have any other access?

Comment: @Robby1212 No man I don't have any access I am really worried and crying man.

Comment: In that case you may need to contact the AWS tech line and ask them to reset your server if no other can be gained.

Comment: @Robby1212 but data is most important. How can I recover data?

Comment: @shahrushabh recreate a instance and restore a backup. Backups are not optional when using a VPS. I am fairly certain you lost your data if you do not have a backup.

Comment: @Rinzwind My server is running and I have a snapshot of my data. Just tell me How can I recover data from the snapshot?

Comment: @shahrushabh a snapshof of the data BEFORE the chmod? ;-) If you do: recreate the instance, and mount your snapshot inside it.

Comment: @Rinzwind no it after the chmod command executed.